# Smearing estimate for cubic root transform in linear regression

Tags: regression, modeling, back-transformation, cubic, duan-smearing

I am building a cost model with cubic root transformation of the cost. Hence dependent variable is (cost)^(1/3). Now, am at a stage where i need to re-transform the predicted value to the actual cost. But while re-transforming, i have read that we need to apply a smearing factor rather than directly taking the cube of the predicted value. Have a 2 part question:

1. Smear factor is calculated as mean(g(residual)), where g() is the anti-transformation function. How are the residuals calculated here? Are these taken from the development data or the holdout data?
2. Browsed through various websites, all had the calculation explained for log transformation function. In that case, smear factor is calculated as D1=mean(exp(residual)) and this value is multiplied by the predicted value as y1=D1.exp(XBETA). Now, how to get and implement the same logic for cubic root transformation? Following the same methodology, I could calculate the factor as D2=mean(residual^3). Now applying this factor seems a concern. I could consider y1 as exp{XBETA+log[mean(exp(residual))]}. On the same lines, can I consider y2 = {XBETA+D2^(1/3)}^3, i.e, {XBETA+[(mean(residual^3))^(1/3)]}^3. Does this makes sense?

Hope the questions are clear.

Comment: nobody to answer..! :(